# Comparing execution plans

Tags: execution-plan

How does the optimizer compare different execution plans of the same query?
Let's say we have two complex and structurally different execution plans, how can I know if they are providing the same result?

Comment: If the optimizer produces 2 different plans for the same query, they better be producing the same results. Otherwise, there is a bug in the optimizer.

Comment: You don't specify RDBMS and this question is far too broad anyway. SQL Server has various transformation rules that can be applied to sub trees to produce logically equivalent sub trees. It keeps track of these in the memo structure. See [Query Optimizer Deep Dive](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/04/28/query-optimizer-deep-dive-part-1.aspx) and [Inside the Optimizer: Constructing a Plan](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/07/29/inside-the-optimiser-constructing-a-plan.aspx) for some more details.

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith for the links, I wasn't aware of these transformation rules.

Comment: @ypercube - Except if the query uses non deterministic expressions such as filtering on `ROW_NUMBER` ordered on a non unique column.

Comment: @MartinSmith, right, if the query is non-deterministic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task of an optimizer is to create several execution plans and compare them (typically by costs). Each execution plan can be seen as logical transformation.

For example: a simple join would always be the cartesian product of two tables. Each row from the first is read and combined with each row in the other table. Than the join condition is checked and the resulting row is used or discarded.

That would be our live without optimizer. The optimizer is using set theory and boolean algebra to transform it. Each transformation leads to the same result. For instance tt doesn't matter if you first sort two sets independent and join them afterwards or first join them and sort them as one.

Other optimizations are the way rows are fetched or compared. There are for example many join algorithms like nested loop join, hash join or sort-merge join. Each algorithm has different advantages and disadvantages. But they operate on the same data. The only (hypothetical) way a execution plan could lead to other results is a difference in rows stored and the index. For that reason the indices have to be always updated as a row is inserted/updated/deleted.

Comment: If all transformations lead to the same result, what makes the specificity of an execution plan?

Comment: Some execution plans are faster than others. Faster can be for example: less cpu, less io.